# Using Pearson correlation in sklearn FeatureAgglomeration

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, affinity

I have a pandas dataframe with 100 rows and 10,000 features. I want to fit hierarchical clustering on my data by using pearson correlation as the affinity argument in [sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration.html).

I've tried two ways to make it work so far:
The first is:

```
feature_agglomator = FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters=10, affinity=np.corrcoef, linkage='average')
```

The second one:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import correlation 
feature_agglomator = FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters=10,affinity='correlation', linkage='average')
```

After running:

```
feature_agglomator.fit_transform(X)
```

Both ended with the same exception:

```
ValueError: The condensed distance matrix must contain only finite values.
```

What can I do for it to work propery?

Comment: I think you should read these two github threads related to your issue:
[link]https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7689
[link]https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10076
Both seem to point to point to scipy refusing to perform agglomerative clustering when using cosine distance with zero vectors.

Comment: I think that the correlation is giving you NaN. Check out your input values.

Comment: @Norhther you were right, I had columns filled with 0's. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a fixed error by the author